# Ember - HTML5 Drag and Drop div containing a div

Tags: html, ember.js, drag-and-drop

Quite simply, I seem to have HTML5 Drag and Drop working in an Ember app, but it doesn't seem to work when a draggable div contains another div.
Any ideas appreciated.

eg
This works:

```
<div draggable="true">
    <h1>Drag</h1>
    <h2>Me!</h2>
</div>
```

This doesn't.

```
<div draggable="true">
    <div>
        <h1>Drag</h1>
        <h2>Me!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "work". You aren't able to drag it?

Comment: I want the whole div to be able to be moved immediately to wherever dragged. Haven't tried to write much more yet, just this first step. Seems I can drag something, but no ghost. Really, I need to actually move the whole thing.